# Regarder ou écouter la télévision?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, régionalismes, québec

Les français ont tendance à parler dire "*regarder la télévision*" et les québécois "*écouter la télévision*". 
On peut bien sûr ne faire que regarder si le son est coupé ou ne faire qu'écouter en ne regardant pas l'écran, mais généralement, un téléspectateur regarde **et** écoute sa télévision simultanément.

Pourquoi avoir choisi un verbe plutôt que l'autre? Surtout que l'on parle de télé-*spectateur* (de *spectator*, observateur) mais aussi d'*audi*-mat et *audi*-ence (de *audire*, entendre).

Comment: *Regarder la télévision* et *écouter la télévision*, c'est incorrect. Il faut plus précisément *éteindre la télévision*. Définitivement.

Comment: On pourrait aussi _lire_ la télévision lorsqu'il y a des sous-titres.

Comment: En tous les cas, en ce qui concerne le mot "télévision", le terme veut dire "voir loin". Il semblerait donc que ce soit la vue qui soit privilégiée à l'ouïe.

Comment: @Djaian oui, ce qui, d'une certaine manière, fait de l'expression *regarder la télévision* un pléonasme, et *écouter la télévision* un trait poétique digne du Parnasse...

Comment: Le sourd regarde la télévision, le non-voyant l'écoute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La radio a d'abord été écoutée.

En France, elle a servi de vecteur à la résistance durant la seconde (en espérant qu'il n'y en aura pas de troisième) guerre mondiale ("Ici Londres ...."), les gens avaient l'oreille collée au poste caché aux yeux et aux oreilles des voisins pour ne pas être dénoncés.

On *imaginait* le monde que l'on entendait.

Puis la télévision est arrivée, les images que l'on voyait aux actualités cinématographiques (suite de courts métrages systématiquement diffusés avant le film en noir et blanc enchaînant différents reportages et se terminant toujours par une actualité heureuse) étaient maintenant dans la maison, à table, durant le repas.

On *voyait* maintenant le monde, l'imagination n'avait plus besoin de travailler.

On pouvait même *regarder* les images (sans forcément les comprendre) depuis la mire fixe, jusqu'à la neige qui arrivait lorsque les émetteurs s'arrêtaient.

L'attitude de l'auditeur et du téléspectateur est entièrement différente, on peut faire autre chose en écoutant la radio, on ne peut rien faire d'autre que regarder la télévision, d'autant plus que pendant longtemps, il n'y avait aucune publicité sur les chaînes publiques (et donc pas de nécessité de garder un contact auditif si l'on s'éloignait du poste).

Il semble que l'on doit rapporter *audi-* à *audit* (examiner, juger) et non pas à une question d'oreille.

C'est donc peut-être une question d'histoire qui a entraîné l'usage exclusif du *regard* de ce coté-ci de l'atlantique, mais, pour un esprit cartésien, c'est un non-sens "d'entendre" ce que l'on "voit" (même si la bande son est très riche), c'est aussi une marque d'usages distinctifs des deux techniques.

Comment: Bonne explication pour le choix français, mais cela n'aide pas à la compréhension du choix québécois. Par ailleurs, je ne suis pas d'accord avec "*on ne peut rien faire d'autre que regarder la télévision*" : écouter purement la télévision est possible. L'utilité d'utiliser une télévision plutôt qu'une radio dans ce cas est discutable, certes, mais cela reste possible. (Mais n'explique en rien le choix du verbe *écouter* plutôt que *regarder*, en parlant de la même chose cette fois-ci.)

Comment: @CaramelTruffle Le pouvoir fascinant de la télévision (surtout chez les hommes) vient surtout des reportages, séries ou films diffusés sans rupture publicitaire sur les chaînes publiques. Le 'talk show' ressemble plus à une émission de radio filmée qu'il n'est plus nécessaire de regarder. Il semble être arrivé plus tard dans une France qui reste accrochée à son *exception culturelle* imposant un quota d’œuvres culturelles pour attribuer une fréquence hertzienne aux diffuseurs publics ou privés.

Comment: En plus du *talk-show*, après quelques recherches, j'ai appris que durant les premières années de la télévision au Québec, les émission les plus populaires étaient des radio-feuilletons qui étaient contés au spectateur. (Ex: *Les Plouffe*) L'usage du terme *écouter* pour parler de la télévision s'est donc imposé, car on écoutait bien plus le conteur que l'on regardait son image.

Comment: Origine, explication du -1 ?

Comment: @cl-r: je ne peux pas parler pour le downvoter, mais ta réponse est un peu hors sujet, la question n'est pas à propos d'une différence entre la radio et la télé, mais entre le Québec et le reste de la francophonie.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est un peu le risque d'avoir une réponse limitée à la seule partie que l'on connaît. C'est moins la différence radio/télé que l'impact sur le comportement et le langage que l'utilisation de ces deux moyens de communication ont engendré que j'ai voulu mettre en exergue pour expliquer le choix français. Il semble que cela ait aidé Caramel à mettre en miroir la spécificité canadienne et son origine.

Answer (score 6):

Sur demande, voici une explication de l'emploi du terme « écouter » au Québec. Réponse originellement sous forme de commentaire adressé à la réponse de cl-r :

« Durant les premières années de la télévision au Québec, les émission les plus populaires étaient des radio-feuilletons qui étaient contés au spectateur (*Les Plouffe*, par exemple). L'usage du terme *écouter* pour parler de la télévision s'est donc imposé, car on écoutait bien plus le conteur que l'on ne regardait son image. »

Comment: J'aimerais vous informer, si vous ne le saviez pas, qu'il est possible d'accepter sa propre réponse.

Comment: @Kareen : Merci, mais sauf erreur, il n'est pas possible d'accepter deux réponses, or la mienne et celle de cl-r sont les deux moitiés de l'explication. Ma partie étant déjà en commentaire de celle de cl-r, sa réponse est donc visuellement complète : celui qui la lira (ainsi que ses commentaires) aura l'explication en entier.

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble que la raison est simplement intellectuelle.
C'est comme quand on dit :

> *Tu vois ce que je veux dire ?* Ou bien *Tu m'entends ?*

Quelqu'un de plutôt *visuel* dira *regarder la télévision*, tandis qu'une personne plutôt *auditive* dira plus *écouter la télévision*.

Et comme il y a bien moins d'auditifs que de visuels ...

Comment: (+1) Analyse très pertinente, je crois.

Answer (score 2):

In English, I've never heard somebody say they are listening to the TV if they are watching it too. I tend to have the TV on, but only listen to it whilst I'm doing web work, but I would still say "I'm watching tele."

I'd say the verbs were chosen from radio being invented first, so people have always associated listening to radio and when viewing was introduced with TV's, watching was linked to TV's.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I fail to see how that answers why two different verbs are used in French. An explanation about English usage does not automatically transposes itself to another language.

Answer (score 1):

La raison est que les québécois ont souvent leurs propres mots et expressions, différents des français.

Ils diront, par exemple, "ton char" au lieu de "ta voiture" ; on comprend le sens (même parfois difficilement pour des francophones) mais cela reste spécifique à leur français.

Emploie le verbe regarder pour la télévision et tout le monde devrait te comprendre

Comment: Bienvenue sur le site Jackyto. Ta réponse est correcte mais tu n'expliques pas pourquoi l'un des deux verbes a été choisi plutôt que l'autre.

Answer (score 1):

En France les deux sont acceptables, mais sont utilisés dans des cas de figure différents, liés selon moi à l'importance du discours ou a contrario de l'image diffusés à l'écran.

En cas de doute, dans tous les cas, "regarder" est OK, mais dans certains cas écouter est plus adapté et plus riche de sens :

- On "écoute François Hollande" répondre à une interview de plusieurs minutes à la télévision, ou bien on écoute un débat entre deux philosophes, par ce que dans ces cas la parole de la personne est importante, plus que l'image vue à l'écran, et aussi parce que cette action d'écouter constitue le principal effort de ce moment.
- En revanche on regarde les informations, par ce que dans ce cas c'est souvent l'image qui prend le dessus à l'écran.

Answer (score 1):

Lorsque François Hollande ou tout autre personnage répond à une interview à la télévision, selon moi, il est pertinent de "regarder" le non-verbal de la personne qui parle. Il est utile de voir la physionomie d'une personne à la télé. Ne serait-ce que de voir un humoriste au petit écran et ses mimiques pour percevoir un niveau supérieur du sens de ses mots. Moi je regarde la télévision et j'écoute la radio. Il m'est impossible de voir la télé et écouter la radio simultanément sans couper l'audio de la télé.

Answer (score 1):

Le terme ASSISTER à une émission serait peut-être le plus approprié.

Answer (score 0):

Chers amis francophones,

il serait temps d'ajouter un nouveau mot multimédia au dictionnaire français, tel que « audio-visionner » une émission, un bulletin de nouvelles ou un reportage à la télévision...

Cela n'empêcherait pas qu'une personne pourrait regarder ou visionner l'écran du téléviseur sans vouloir ou pouvoir en écouter le son.

À l'inverse, une autre personne pourrait écouter la télévision sans vouloir ou pouvoir visionner l'écran.

Le dictionnaire français devrait inclure un mot plus précis, tel que « audio-visionner », qui reflèterait l'usage simultané des fonctions sensorielles visuelles et auditives afin de décoder les messages visuels, langagiers, mélodiques, ainsi que les autres indices sonores émis par la télévision.

Merci!

Comment: Il reste à le suggérer à MM Larousse, Robert ...

Comment: Si vous savez comment relayer cette information, à quelle adresse exactement, faites le moi savoir. Merci!

Comment: Je pense qu'il doit y avoir une page contact sur leur site respectif.