# Quelle préposition est employée correctement dans « D’après ce que j’ai entendu de/dans l’aperçu, le programme sera très divertissant! »

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions

D’après ce que j’ai entendu dans l’aperçu, le programme sera très divertissant.

D’après ce que j’ai entendu de l’aperçu, le programme sera très intéressant.

Ici j’emploie « aperçu » au sens de « avant-première », présentation publicitaire d'extraits d'une émission de télévision programmée pour une date ultérieure.

Comment: Les 2 semblent bons avec des sens différents, il faudrait préciser.

Comment: Quels sont ces deux sens?

Comment: Il s’agit d’échanges entre comédiens (que j’ai) entendus durant la diffusion de cette avant-première.

Comment: Si vous pensez que la formulation peut prêter à plusieurs interprétations, n’hésitez pas à m’en proposer une meilleure. Je vous en serai reconnaissant.

Comment: J’ai cherché à être le plus concis que possible, mais on pourrait très bien aborder d’autres points, entre autres la complicité  des comédiens, l’atmosphère...

Comment: alors plutôt "dans" (pas le temps de rédiger, désolé).

Comment: D'après ce que j'ai aperçu dans l'aperçu, le divertissement sera très divertissant ;-)

Comment: J'emploierais le terme bande-annonce plutôt qu'aperçu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La tournure :

> D’après ce que j’ai entendu dans l’aperçu...

ne passe pas pour moi. C'est peut-être parce que je suis français. Je regarde la télé alors qu'au Québec, [on l'écoute](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6624/regarder-ou-%C3%A9couter-la-t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vision). Je bloque aussi à cause de la contradiction entre l'ouïe (entendu) et la vue (aperçu), d'où ma blague en commentaire (*d'après ce que j'ai aperçu dans l'aperçu*). Ce fameux aperçu, je comprends de quoi il s'agit mais je ne suis pas très habitué à ce mot dans ce contexte. Je m'attends plutôt à *bande-annonce*, comme @Laurent S., ou à *extrait*.

Avec deux modifications, on obtient ces deux débuts de phrases :

> D’après ce que j’ai vu dans la bande-annonce...

> D’après ce que j’ai vu de la bande-annonce...

J'y vois une légère nuance. Dans le deuxième, je n'ai vu qu'une partie de la bande annonce.

Avec *bande-annonce*, le verbe entendre ne me choque plus et on arrive à cette troisième proposition:

> D’après ce que j’ai entendu de la bande-annonce...

Ici, je n'ai pas vu du tout la bande-annonce mais j'ai entendu une ou plusieurs personnes qui l'ont vue, et qui on donné leur avis à partir duquel je forge le mien (c'est à dire: *d'après ce que j'ai entendu dire de la bande annonce*). Un autre sens possible est que j'ai entendu une petite partie du son de la bande-annonce.

Enfin, on peut aussi utiliser *dans* pour arriver à:

> D’après ce que j’ai entendu dans la bande-annonce...

Là, j'ai entendu de la musique, des paroles ou quoi que ce soit de la bande-son de la bande-annonce et ça me permet de donner mon avis.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux prépositions sont utilisables, mais avec des sens légèrement différents.

Donné le présent contexte, « dans » sert  à stipuler la situation, la place où se trouve la chose, cette place étant nommée par le complément de cette préposition.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dans)) B.− P. ext. 1. Dans précise la situation d'un élément qui est intégré à un ensemble déterminé.

« De », dans ce contexte indique  que la chose en question (ici la chose entendue) est une partie  de la chose signifiée par le complément.

([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de))¹ **I. A. 6.**  Le point de départ est un tout dont on tire une partie.
a) Verbe + de.Donner de son temps (de « un peu, une partie de »).

([réf. 1 -  1851](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Xy5HAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA208&dq=%22vu+de+cette%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg0rqMxabuAhUIzhoKHQ6NAxkQ6AEwBHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22vu%20de%20cette%22&f=false)) On a vu de cette artiste , dans les salons de 1808 à 1824 , une douzaine de bustes , dont ceux de P. Lescot , du graveur Gérard Audran et du géographe Nicolas Samson […]

([réf. - 2014](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yzyqBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT50&dq=%22vu+de+cette%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjox423yKbuAhVJA2MBHUzFB1kQ6AEwA3oECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22vu%20de%20cette%22&f=false)) Voilà tout ce que j'ai vu de cette fameuse promenade.

([réf. - 1841](https://books.google.fr/books?id=1-IkAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP196&dq=%22vu+de+cette%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjox423yKbuAhVJA2MBHUzFB1kQ6AEwEnoECC0QAg#v=onepage&q=%22vu%20de%20cette%22&f=false)) Le premier pied que nous ayons vu de cette plante remarquable était exposé , il y a plus de dix ans , à l ' étalage de  madame Prévost , fleuriste au Palais - Royal , et fut acheté par feu notre célèbre peintre Redouté .

([réf. - 1836](https://books.google.fr/books?id=gWRXJ6oFPgAC&pg=PA488&dq=%22vu+de+cette%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjox423yKbuAhVJA2MBHUzFB1kQ6AEwF3oECDQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22vu%20de%20cette%22&f=false)) D'après ce que j'ai vu de cette maladie dont les plus gros étaient entièrement libres dans le fluide, je suis porté à croire […]

Remarquer que dans aucun des quatre exemples il n'est possible d'utiliser « dans » sauf le second, et selon le contexte cette préposition peut être ambigüe  ; pour utiliser « dans » dans le premier cas il faut changer « de cette artiste » en « de la production de cette artiste ».

D’après ce que j’ai entendu dans l’aperçu, le programme sera très divertissant.
*Il y a une chose que j'ai entendue dans l'aperçu qui laisse penser que le programme sera très divertissant.*

D’après ce que j’ai entendu de l’aperçu, le programme sera très intéressant.
*La partie de l'aperçu que j'ai entendue laisse penser que le programme sera très intéressant.*

« Dans » ne dit pas si tout l'aperçu a été entendu, mais « de » dit que tout n'a pas été entendu.
En utilisant « dans » on dit plutôt qu'une chose spécifique dans l'aperçu entraine la conclusion alors qu'avec « de » on dit que la conclusion vient d'une partie seulement de l'aperçu, en laissant un doute sur ce que le reste de l'aperçu peut réserver dans le sens de contribuer à une impression finale.

¹ <sub>Grâce à commentaire par [**user Thélée_Lavoie**](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/25619/th%c3%a9l%c3%a9e-lavoie) (Avec ctrl-f en cherchant « verbe » dans le texte de « de », on peut voir des trucs comme origine ou condition préalable, possiblement une de ces choses-là... )</sub>

Comment: Avec ctrl-f en cherchant « verbe » dans le texte de « de », on peut voir des trucs comme _origine_ ou _condition préalable_, possiblement une de ces choses-là...